# How do you find eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a differential operator A?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

How do you find eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a differential operator A? I'm very lost so if someone could explain this to me using examples for first and second-order differential operators that would be great!

Comment: The eigenfunctions and eigenvalues of a simple differential operator
$$
         Lf = -\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}f + Vf
$$
are impossibly complex for a general potential $V=V(x)$. You can study a wide range of Quantum Mechanical systems with such an equation. I think you're going to have to be more specific. For example, are you looking at differential operators with constant coefficients?

Comment: The specific problem I was given is "suppose A is the differential operator A = (d/dx + 2)^2. Find all eigenvalues and eigenvectors. What is the multiplicity of each of its eigenvalues?"

Comment: Are you working on a finite interval with endpoint conditions? Or do you want solutions of $(d/dx+2)^{2}f=0$? Or do you want solutions of $(d/dx+2)^{2}f = \lambda f$ for all $\lambda$?

Comment: The only other thing it says in the problem is "Recall that if A : V → V is a linear operator on the vector space V, then a vector v ∈ V is an eigenvector of A if Av = λv for some number λ, which is called the eigenvalue."

Comment: So I think it may be the last one you are suggesting.

Comment: Have they defined the vector space $V$ for you? And do they allow general complex $\lambda$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they're not describing $V$ or imposing conditions, then you want solutions of
$$
                 (\frac{d}{dx}+2)^{2}f = \lambda f \\
                 (\frac{d}{dx}+2-\sqrt{\lambda})(\frac{d}{dx}+2+\sqrt{\lambda})f = 0.
$$
The solutions are
$$
                  f(x) = Ae^{-2x-\sqrt{\lambda}x}+Be^{-2x+\sqrt{\lambda}x}.
$$
The exception is where $2-\sqrt{\lambda}=2+\sqrt{\lambda}$ or $\sqrt{\lambda}=0$. In that case, the solutions are
$$
                     f(x) = (Ax+B)e^{-2x}.
$$
**For a general second order operator with constant coefficients**, you can reduced to a factored form:
$$
                 (\frac{d}{dx}-\mu_{1})(\frac{d}{dx}-\mu_{2})f=0.
$$
If $\mu_{1} \ne \mu_{2}$, then the general solution is
$$
                   Ae^{\mu_{1}x}+Be^{\mu_{2}x}.
$$
If $\mu_{1}=\mu_{2}$, then the general solution is
$$
                      (Ax+B)e^{\mu_{1}x}.
$$

Comment: @Olivia : You're welcome.